# convert TYPO3 6.2 with tt_news to TYPO3 7.6 with news

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news, tt-news

I have to update an 6.2 installation with ext:tt_news to 7.6 with ext:news. what is the best way to do the news conversion at the moment?

should I start converting the news records in 6.2 and then update to 7.6 (drawback: ext:news runs only until version 3.2.8 with TYPO3 6.2)?

or first update to 7.6 and then convert to news?

I have found ext:news_ttnewsimporter. the last version is from october 2016. is it compatible to the latest version of ext:news ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would upgrade the current installation to 7 LTS. There you can use the newest EXT:news version and you need one step less for migrating.

For importing there is a migrate tool in EXT:news to migrate all tt_news tables and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think First upgrade 7 LTS is best way and standard for tt_news to news systems migration.

After upgrade 7 LTS, you migration tt_news to news using `news_ttnewsimport` extension

For migration tt_news to news click here [migration tt_news to news](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/3.0.0/Main/Tutorial/MigrationFromTtNews/Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have an TYPO3 6.2 running and migrated from EXT:tt_news to EXT:news. I had no problems using EXT:news_ttnewsimporter for migration. You just have to use the related versions of the extensions that are for TYPO3 6.2.

So I would migrate to EXT:news first on TYPO3 6.2 as you also have to change the templates. And after, the upgrade to TYPO 7.6 should be easier.